# JS - Merge two subobjects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working with objects that have subobjects inside, and I want to merge, for example, these objects:

```
subType:
   type:
      name: 
        contains: "e"
```

and:

```
subType:
  name:
    contains: "A"
```

The result that I want:

```
subType:
  name:
    contains: "A"
  type:
    name: 
       contains: "e"
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `newObj.subtype = {...obj1.subType, ...obj2.subType}`

Comment: It would help if you described your objects in actual JavaScript syntax, but as @Barmar says, object spread syntax would seem the simplest.

Comment: If yaml is a project requirement, the js-yaml project will help you convert to and from yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the spread operator `...` you can take all fields of an object. You can use it to create a new object with all fields of the other objects.

In general, something like:

```
var merged = {...object1.subType, ...object2.subType}
```

Beware, in case of fields on both objects, the last one is taken (including all its subfields).

Answer (score -1):

Use `$.extend()` from jquery. Refrence https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

In your case, the code would be like belows:

```js
// solution 1
let merged = $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);

// solution 2
$.extend(obj1, obj2);
let merged = obj1;
```

Comment: While this may work, it may not be the best suggestion if the user is not already using jQuery (e.g. I'd make the same remarks on a question suggesting lodash).

Comment: @crashmstr yup, I didn't know that `spread` operator. I've learned a lot, thanks :(